# AWS API Gateway Stage URL is faster than Custom Domain URL. How to improve Custom Domain URL response time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

My API gateway is in us-west-2. There is a custom domain as well. I want to use the custom domain URLs. When I load tested /health endpoint from us-west-2, API gateway stage URL performed better than the custom domain URL. custom domain /health URL is around 2 times slower than the API gateway /health URL.
What can I do to improve this?
The custom domain name is "Edge Optimized".

Comment: Which type of custom URL are you using, and have you added anything in front of its endpoint such as a CDN?

Comment: I can see the domain name is present in Route53.

Comment: If its "Edge Optimized" then you have CloudFront in front. Try creating a "Regional" one and compare against that.

Comment: Yes you can have 2 seperate custom domains on a single api gateway

Comment: I do not want to try 'regional' because the client can be using the REST endpoint from Chicago/Las Vegas.

Answer (score 1):

APIG url's are Edge Optimized meaning they're spread out across AWS infrastructure.

You need to create an edge optimized custom domain as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-edge-optimized-custom-domain-name.html) - let me know if you need any additional guidance!

Comment: The custom domain name configuration shows, it is "Edge Optimized".

Comment: Does your route53 record point at the cloudfront distribution?

Comment: alias target has entry <sometext>.cloudfront.net but when I search for this string in CloudFront, it is not present under "distribution" list

Comment: Hrmm interesting so it won't be as APIG distributions are hidden in the cf console. Err Lemmy have a think a sec, how are you measuring it by the way?

Comment: By the way if you hit my profile->developer story and connect on LinkedIn we can probably debug together and figure it out since I might need info that doesn't really wanna be shared here.

Comment: Then we can come back with the solution. Unless anyone else comes up with an answer first.

Comment: I am running BlazeMeter script from cloud location aws-west-2. The script has 1 endpoint /health, I am measuring 90th percentile.